# Twitter Streaming Spark : how many filter keywords can i have with a streaming context?

Tags: twitter, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using a spark streaming context to stream twitter data using the api below in scala.
  https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/streaming/twitter/TwitterUtils.html

I wanted to know how many filter keywords can I give to create streaming function?. (3rd parameter of the function below)

```
TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc,None,keywords)
```

How many filter keywords can the twitter API handle.

Comment: I would really appretiate if people let me know the reason the question was downvoted?. This will help me get better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enter a set of keywords as a filter to track twitter, according to current limitations you can track up to 400 keywords.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://twittercommunity.com/t/streaming-api-volume/7544), it seems that twitter limits you not according to the numer of filters you supply, but the overall volume you're allowed to consume. It seems like the limit is %1 of total tweets.